# Tilting Screen to Scroll UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion

I have a UIScrollView that when I tilt the iPhone, I want the view to scroll. Please note that I want to scroll two `dimensionally`, upwards and side to side. I've looked everywhere for answers, [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374367/having-issue-with-scrolling-image-with-gyroscope). Here's some code:

```
self.motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: {
        (motion:CMDeviceMotion!, error:NSError!) in

        let xRotationRate = motion.rotationRate.x
        let yRotationRate = motion.rotationRate.y
        let zRotationRate = motion.rotationRate.z

            let xoffset = CGFloat(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x) + CGFloat(xRotationRate)

            let contentOffset:CGPoint = CGPointMake(offset, 0)
            self.scrollView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated:true)


    })
```

Even with this extremely simplified code, I can't get feedback on my phone that is consistent with the rotation of the device. All the views in the scroll view just seem to slowly move to the top of the screen. How would you scroll two dimensionally by `tilting the device`.