# Tilt scroll with gyroscope in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, gyroscope, core-motion

I am trying to get the scrolling effect on my UIScrollView on screen tilt horizontally.
I have this function which I invoke in viewDidLoad() :

```
func setupMotionManager() {

        motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1/60
        let motionMovingRate = 4.0
        let maxXOffset = self.scrollView.contentSize.width - self.scrollView.frame.size.width
        let minXOffset = CGFloat(0.0)

        motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: .main, withHandler: { (data, error) in
            if (fabs((data?.rotationRate.y)!) >= 0.1) {
                var targetX = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - CGFloat(data!.rotationRate.y * motionMovingRate)

                if (targetX > maxXOffset) {
                    targetX = maxXOffset
                } else if (targetX < minXOffset) {
                    targetX = minXOffset
                }

                self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: targetX, y: CGFloat(0.0))
                print(data!.rotationRate.y)
            }
        })

    }
```

I took the code from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374367/having-issue-with-scrolling-image-with-gyroscope?noredirect=1&lq=1).
I don't know why but it does not work properly. I can see that rotation rate is changing, but the content of the scrollView does not move. 
Any ideas? Help, please.

Comment: Does your scrollView work without gyroscop?

Comment: Yes, it does. I have disabled user interaction inside scrollView, because I scroll the content inside programmatically, like an animation. However after animation is finished scrollView does not react to gyroscope.